# How to save webpage from UIWebview for Offline Browsing

Tags: ios, uiwebview, offline-browsing

Does anyone have idea, how to download HTML page from `UIWebview` along with the resources - for offline storage, so user will be able to access web page, even when there is no internet.

It should be achieved without `ASIWebPageRequest`, since `ASIWebPageRequest`downloads a webpage directly from URL. I need to save webpage directly from `UIWebview`, so that values of radio buttons, textfields etc input by user can be preserved, and load it in the same state later.

Actually, I am displaying surveys webpage offline. If user downloads a webpage after filling some information, it has to be saved in that state. When user opens app later, he should find webpage in the state he left off last time.

Any suggestions are welcome. **Please note** that this Question is not about caching webpage. It has to be saved in directory. Thanks.

Comment: save in documents directory.

Comment: Did you solve this? It would really help me :)